# Python app behaving weirdly when opened in command prompt

Tags: python, command-prompt

Good evening everyone!

So I am learning python right now using a tutorial and for the step I am currently on I need to use colorama and prompt_toolkit packages in order to make some parts of text more colorful and to make the program automatically complete user's input, since the second thing can't be done in pycharm, I need to run the application in cmd prompt.

However when I attempt that via the "D:\Projects\rpsgame\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/Projects/rpsgame/rock-paper-scissors.py" given me by pycharm, the output is being displayed incorrectly(as seen below, instead of those ←[37 and ←[95m there should be blank spaces).

```
C:\Users\****>D:\Projects\rpsgame\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/Projects/rpsgame/rock-paper-scissors.py
←[37m
←[95m
----------------------------------
       Rock Paper Scissors
----------------------------------
←[37m

LEADERS:
2 -- Makie

----------------------------------

1 -- Not-Makie

----------------------------------

Player 1, what is your name?
```

Colors aren't displaying neither. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using command prompt on windows, you have to use  `colorama.init()` to output colors according to it's [documentation](https://github.com/tartley/colorama#initialisation).

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot!
Will make a note to check documentation before posting a question next time :)